# MySQL table partition truncation not to propagate on a slave

Tags: mysql

I have a table `now`. It has 7 seven partitions, and each day I truncate a partition(not delete, just empty the partition).

I have a use case where I would like to have a full backup of the table as well. The backup I want to keep is obviously on some other instance preferably a slave.

So in concise form, I want to know if is it possible that truncation query never runs on slave.

But other queries, runs fine.

I am open to any other better approach to achieve the same.

Answer (score 0):

You do a `TRUNCATE PARTITION` on the Master daily, correct?  And you do not want that to be done on the Slave, correct?

If yes, then

```
SET SQL_LOG_BIN = 0;
TRUNCATE ...;
SET SQL_LOG_BIN = 1;
```

https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/set-sql-log-bin.html

But, beware.  Once you have more than, say, 100 partitions, the table is likely to be slower and slower on the Slave.  And, at some point you will hit the maximum number of partitions.

I can't think of any thing that will "break" because of having more data (and more partitions) on the Slave than on the Master.  I assume you never otherwise modify the data in 'old' partitions.